# customErrors no funciona con targetFramework="4.8"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, aspx

Tengo un proyecto de pagina web con Webforms version .Net 4.8 donde no funciona el redireccionamiento si hay error a la pagina de errores.
En otro proyecto con .Net 4.5 me funciona bien.

He mirado el Webconfig en el proyecto con .Net 4.8 y tengo lo siguiente:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/error.aspx"> 
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: ¿Que mensaje te arroja? Directo el error? esto te sucede en la maquina de desarrollo o en un servidor de PROD/QA/TEST (o ambiente fuera de desarrollo)?

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez cuando hay una excepción o error de cualquier clase debería redirigirme a la pagina "~/ErrorPages/error.aspx" pero no lo hace. En cambio si lo pruebo en otro proyecto que esta hecho con NET 4.5 si hay un error me redirige sin problemas.